# Pullback of a map

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

I've read on the website ncatlab.org that a pullback is defined as the subset of a cartesian product $A \times C$ of two sets $A \rightarrow B \leftarrow C$. I've also read about a pullback in the context of ' coordinate rings ' insomuch as a pullback of ' C - Algebras ' maps $u^2 + v^3 \in \mathbb{C}[W] \rightarrow W$ to $(x^{2}y)^{2} + (x - z)^{3} \in \mathbb{C}[V] \rightarrow V$.

I could not see which tuples make up the cartesian product though!

[image]

Comment: These are two different senses of pullbacks. The first is a _categorical_ pullback (think dual to a categorical pushout). The second is in the sense of induced maps, (think dual to a pushforward). Sometimes the two do sort of intersect, such as in pullback bundles.

Comment: Conceptually they're not unrelated. There's a close relationship between categorical pullbacks and variable substitution (as is happening in the picture), though not being familiar with the gear of algebraic geometry I can't say whether or not the above is strictly a categorical pullback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Osama Ghani has hit the nail on the head in the comments. Your definition that you've written in the post is of a categorical pullback, which is not appropriate in this setting. There is another notion of pullback: often times when one has a function, sheaf, or some other gadget defined on an object $Y$, given an appropriate map of objects $f:X\to Y$, we can produce a gadget on $X$ from the data of our gadget on $Y$ and the map $f:X\to Y$. This is frequently referred to as a *pullback*, and the method that defines it is called *pulling back* our gadget along $f$.

In our specific case, we're dealing with regular functions on a variety $Y$ and a map of varieties $f:X\to Y$. By the definition of a morphism of varieties, any regular function $\varphi$ on $Y$ defines a regular function $f^*\varphi$ on $X$ via the rule $(f^*\varphi)(x)=\varphi(f(x))$. This is called the *pullback* of $\varphi$ (by $f$), and it gives a morphism of coordinate algebras as defined at the top of the page.